# What tool is this?

Tags: hand-tools

Is marked General, Made in the USA No. 811 1/16 on one side, 1/8 on the other [image]

Comment: + 1 for wooden ruler on on a wood board displaying a tool with a wood handle on  woodworking stack.

Comment: Looks like a Fiskars brand wooden ruler.

Answer (score 6):

I want to say an edge chamfer tool. For taking off the hard corner of a board. Like a chamfer bit for a router.

Comment: Definitely agree-- looks a lot like the [veritas cornering tool](https://www.woodcraft.com/products/veritas-cornering-tool-set?gclid=CjwKCAjwp_zkBRBBEiwAndwD9QdHpZwafiFdLLwAUPcE5lnwwPeTs-AGbbn4IxvjBHbI76DxBb-6aBoCEv4QAvD_BwE)

Comment: Yup, that's what it is. For a tool that stayed in production for such a long time they apparently don't work that well!

Comment: Thank you all VERY much. It is indeed called a cornering tool. No mention whatsoever in any of the old General catalogs. I have two off them, and in all my years of collecting had never seen one. When I saw them yesterday in the flea market I thought they were bottle openers. Once more thanks for solving the mistery

Comment: It would be appreciated if you select the answer as correct so it does not keep getting bumped by the community in the future and beyond.